# Limitations of Hive's INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am a bit of surprised to know that Hive now has UPDATE statement (although it looks like its way back from v0.14), although I am quite aware for some time that it is in Hive's roadmap to have a full or near RDBMS-SQL functionality.

Can you summarize how Hive's INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE different from Relational Databases and what are its limitations (Hive is v2.1.0 as of this writing)?

Should Hive continue to improve its RDBMS-like SQL capabilities, say 2-3 years time, will it then be useful for Relational DB workloads?

(I'm not aware of the full roadmap though. Pardon if this is a stupid question, or a question due to laziness in browsing through documentations.)

Answer (score 0):

Hive supported insert. However for update and delete operation following are the requirements
only for ORC format
only for bucketed tables
have to specify TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")

The latency is still an issue with this operations following has use cases of why ACID compatibility is introduced.  However in road map hive is not planning to replace transaction relational database.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations